# how to render html markup on a jsf page

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF page where I display data from different rss feeds. Sometimes this data contains html markup elements, but when I put them inside a p:outputLabel they are displayed on the page like plain text filled with markup elements written out. Is there a way to either ignore these elements or to render them properly? Unfortunately I haven't found much on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `escape` attribute for the control to `false`. The default is true to prevent interpretation of any content as html.

`<p:outputLabel value="#{bean.text}" escape="false"/>`

Comment: `<p:outputLabel>` is not the right tool for this problem. It would be better to use `<h:outputText>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `escape="true"` in `<h:outputText>`:

```html
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="true" />
```

---

Note that `<p:outputLabel>` will render a `<label>` HTML commponent, which should be used as label for other components like `<p:inputText>`. It is not for writing direct content in your HTML.